# Suitable design pattern for Dynamic Runtime Configurations

Tags: spring-boot, design-patterns, architecture, software-design, low-level

I am working on a spring boot application in java. I have a case where I need to pick up some runtime configuration(which can change dynamically without any need of deployment or rebooting the app) and use it in all the classes further ahead. It basically stores all the plug and play configurations I want my app to support.

I have tried listener pattern but it doesn't seem to be the best option since I don't want that config to be listened by a few, rather I want that config to flow through whole of the code.

Is there an existing design pattern or a technique that is a standard for such activity?

Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

In general you need to store the application configuration externally and then listen to changes on that. How the change is notified depends on the runtime environment. For example cloud platforms may have separate decoupled notification systems, desktop application may want to implement a file change listener and so on.

This pattern is generally called Runtime Reconfiguration Pattern (see [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/dn589785%28v%3Dpandp.10%29)). In conclusion there is no magic that will apply the changes throughout your code, but you will need to listen for the changes and adjust the runtime behavior based on those.